# I am trying to update the profile photo along with other form data using react-router-dom action. But req.file is showing undefined in the backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I am trying to update the profile photo along with other form data using react-router-dom action. But req.file is showing undefined in the backend.Backend is working fine while using postman, But showing req.file undefined when working with react.
React code

```
export async function updateAction({ request, params }) {
    const formData = await request.formData()
    const token = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3080/users/update',
        {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            body: formData
        })
    const responseData = await response.json()
    console.log("hehehe", responseData)
    return redirect('/profile')

}
```

nodejs backend code

```
Route.patch('/update', auth, upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.file)
    try {
        await req.user.updateOne(req.body)
        if (req.body.password) {
            req.user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 8)
        }
        if (req.file) {
            req.user.avatar = req.file.buffer
        }
        await req.user.save()
        res.status(200).send({ message: 'Profile updated successfully' })
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})
```

I tried to save the req.file.buffer in the database.But req.file is showing undefined in the backend.